# Vuex async/await on dispatch

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuex

I'm using async await to dispatch an action but it clears the form inputs before the form is sent and I end up with empty values, how do I send the form first and then clear it afterwards?

```
    async submit() {
      try {
         await this.$store.dispatch('AddDelivery', this.form)
      } catch (error) {
        return
      } finally {
        this.form.firstName 
        = this.form.lastName 
        = this.form.address1 
        = this.form.address2 
        = this.form.postcode 
        = this.form.city 
        = this.form.phone 
        ='';

      }
    }
```

Comment: it looks as if its caused because vues obviously reactive, do crude unhook/copy before passing `await this.$store.dispatch('AddDelivery', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form)))`, or pass whats needed, prob get away with `{...this.form}`

Comment: Are you returning a suitable promise from `AddDelivery`?

Comment: AddDelivery doesn't make an API call it just commits a mutation and updates the store

Comment: Could you add more code about `AddDelivery`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AddDelivery` action needs to return the promise. Then use as below

```
const addDelivery = async function() {
  try {
    return this.$store.dispatch('AddDelivery', this.form)
  } catch (error) {
    return
  }
}
function submit() {
  addDelivery().then(() => {
    console.log('Clear data here')
    this.form.firstName 
    = this.form.lastName 
    = this.form.address1 
    = this.form.address2 
    = this.form.postcode 
    = this.form.city 
    = this.form.phone 
    ='';
  })
}
```

**or**

```
function submit() {
      this.$store.dispatch('AddDelivery', this.form)
        .then(() => {
        console.log('Clear data here')
        this.form.firstName 
        = this.form.lastName 
        = this.form.address1 
        = this.form.address2 
        = this.form.postcode 
        = this.form.city 
        = this.form.phone 
        ='';
      })
    }
```